# How does a stack-allocated vector expand in c++?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, callstack

If I declare a vector like so:

```
int main() {
    vector<string> names;
    int something_else_on_the_stack = 0;
    names.add("John");
    names.add("Annie");
}
```

How are you actually able to "add" elements to the names vector? If names is stack-allocated, shouldn't "something_else_on_the_stack" be right after it on the stack? Then how can you add names to the already allocated vector?

Comment: pardon me if I'm wrong, but isn't std::vector data always heap allocated?

Comment: @AndreasHenning the vector is stack allocated, it's data usually is dynamically allocated, but the C++ standard doesn't say anything about stacks or heaps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Internally, a `vector<string>` will most likely consist of a `string*` pointing at the actual data and probably two more `size_t` members indicating occupied and reserved memory. All the rest will be on the heap. Therefore, `sizeof(vector<string>)` is fixed, and the allocation on the stack won't change.

Answer (score 7):

`std::vector` internaly maintains a pointer to heap allocated space that is resized as necessary. The footprint on the stack doesn't change.

Answer (score 2):

The size that a `vector<string>` occupies on the stack is fixed, and will typically be equal to the size of 3 pointers (this is implementation specific). The pointers point to beginning of storage, vector capacity and vector size. These pointers point to free store memory (or heap, if you want to call it that) that the vector allocates as needed to hold objects you add to the vector.